# Working out the rotation of a sphere from two points on it's surface

Tags: python, rotation, expression, nuke

I'm working in nuke and trying to stabilize a spherical panorama shot on a drone with 6 gopros.
I have been able to 2Dtrack 2 points on the image (supplied to me as an equirectangular map) and convert them to xyz co-ordinates for nukes 3d space.
Now I have to work out either an expression or python script to compute the rotation of the sphere in degrees (x,y,z) on each frame.

I'm ok with python and expressions but am getting quickly out of my depth with the maths.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Missed your image. Please upload the image too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the user is brand new, so he doesn't have the reputation to upload an image yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the third point in an orthonormal frame. It's easy: take the cross product of the vectors defined by the points you're given. Then the rotation will be related to the orthonormal matrix whose rows (or columns) are the three vectors.